# How can I avoid rendering check box numbers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I'm trying to create a comma-separated list of dietary restrictions based on checked boxes in a form.  I managed to make a comma-separated list, but I can’t find a way to keep the app from rendering a number when I click on a checkbox.  Please see below:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            age: "",
            gender: "",
            destination: "",
            dietaryRestrictions: {
                isVegan: false,
                isKosher: false,
                isLactoseFree: false
            }
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }
```

{…more code..}

```
render() {
        const dietR = []
        return (
            <main>
```

{…more code..}

```
[Your dietary restrictions: 
                    {this.state.dietaryRestrictions.isKosher ? dietR.push("Kosher"):null}
                    {this.state.dietaryRestrictions.isLactoseFree ? dietR.push("Lactose-Free"):null}
                    {this.state.dietaryRestrictions.isVegan ? dietR.push("Vegan"):null}
                <p>{dietR.join(", ")}</p>
            </main>
        )
```

Note the “123” after “dietaryRestrictions" in the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Ummmm. Do you mind sharing a minimal implementation on **[StackBlitz](http://stackblitz.com/fork/react)** replicating this issue?

Comment: @SiddAjmera  Thanks for the advice.  This is my first JavaScript question.  I usually post about python and I didn't know how SO feels about having code linked externally instead of present with the question.  Maybe you meant I should do both?  Could you link to a question where someone does this for future reference?  Thanks, again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the way you render:

```
{this.state.dietaryRestrictions.isLactoseFree ? dietR.push("Lactose-Free"):null}
```

`dietR.push("Lactose-Free")`, for example, will return the length of the array. So you can see here since you push one item, you get length 1, then you push another, and so now you  have length 2, and then another, so  you get length 3, so that's the reason you get `123`. So instead of doing the business logic in render where you're changing the array, I would create a method outside the render to do that.

You could say:

```js
const getDietaryRestrictions = () => {
    const dietR = []   
    if(this.state.isKosher)
        dietR.push("Kosher");
    if(this.state.isLactoseFree)
        dietR.push("Lactose-Free");
    if(this.state.isVegan)
        dietR.push("Vegan");
    return dietR;
}
```

And then you could just have

```
<p>{this.getDietaryRestrictions().join(", ")}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks!  Would it be possible to do this with ternary operators?

Comment: No problem! You could maybe do something like `? (() => {dietR.push("Lactose Free"); return "Lactose Free"})() : null` which is called an IIFE but that starts to get messy quick. It's almost always a good idea to handle that business logic outside render.